# I have two generators I wish to chain dependencies on

Tags: cmake

I am trying to build a library which depends upon source (naturally) as well as source which is produced dynamically by two different executables.

First I'll show the source so the context is clear.  App is code in the directory and not prebuilt.

```
add_library(app STATIC app.c)
```

App.c depends upon a generated hdr1.h which is a generated file.  So I add the generation of hdr1.h like so:

```
add_executable(hdr_maker1 src1.c)
```

Hdr_maker1 exe has its own source src1.c but it depends upon a second file hdr2.h which in turn is made
by another exe.

```
add_executable(hdr_maker2 src2.c)
```

Then I try to specify the dependencies and execution of these files so hdr_maker2 runs first to generate hdr2.h which in turn is used by hdr_maker1 when its built to generate hdr1.h which in turn is used by the target library.

```
# pseudo target to make hdr2.h by executing hdr_maker2
add_custom_target(HDR_MAKER2 DEPENDS hdr2.h)
# for the command portion, hdr2.h is specifed a second time
# so that hdr_maker2 makes its output file as hdr2.h
add_custom_command(OUTPUT hdr2.h COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:hdr_maker2> hdr2.h)

# this one depends upon its own src and the generated hdr2.h src
add_custom_target(HDR_MAKER1 DEPENDS hdr1.h hdr2.h)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT hdr1.h COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:hdr_maker1> hdr1.h)

#
add_dependencies(app HDR_MAKER1)
```

The result is that it makes hdr_maker2, but it tries to make hdr_maker1 before it runs hdr_maker2 which makes a required header for hdr_maker2.  This pattern works if I just want to make one pseudo target. ie. if app simply depended upon one .h then it would build and run the maker before it built the app.

FWIW, I've also tried to chain the dependencies by doing this:

```
# hdr_maker1 makes hdr1.h, but depends upon hdr2.h 
# which uses the existing dependncy.
add_custom_target(HDR_MAKER1 DEPENDS hdr1.h)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT hdr1.h COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:hdr_maker1> hdr1.h DEPENDS hdr2.h)
```

I've also tried to chain dependencies like this:

```
#
add_dependencies(app HDR_MAKER1)
add_dependencies(HDR_MAKER1 HDR_MAKER2)
```

Comment: `...but it tries to make hdr_maker1 before it runs hdr_maker2 which makes a required header for hdr_maker2` - Is the last`hdr_maker2` here a misprint? In any case, if your library/executable depends on generated header file, just add this file into sources list: `add_library(app STATIC app.c hdr1.h)`.

Comment: I can try this tomorrow but I doubt it will work. The error occurs while it's trying to build the second generator without running the first.  It's a chain. Exe2 makes hdr 2. Exe 1 require hdr2.h. exe 2 must be built and executed so that it's output can be used to build exe 1. It's failing because exe 2 is not executed. Once exe 1 runs it generates hd1.h.  hdr1.h is used to build the final library.  Your suggestion is appreciated but it most likely will not help.  My understanding is that hdrs listed as sources are ignored.  Also it does not connect execution of exe2 prior to build of exe 1.

Comment: `My understanding is that hdrs listed as sources are ignored.` - Headers are ignored by compiler, but are taken into account in file-level dependency. `Also it does not connect execution of exe2 prior to build of exe 1.` - This connection is adjusted automatically by CMake whenever you use `$<TARGET_FILE:exe2>` generator expression in `add_custom_command`. Moreoever, you may use just `add_custom_command(COMMAND exe2 ...)`, CMake is smart enough for replace exe2 with full path to the executable it creates. BTW, in your code you have two `add_custom_command` with **same *OUTPUT***.

Comment: Tsyvarev, I attempted your suggestion by adding hdr1.h to the lib sources.  It still failed when building the hdr_maker1.   However, I used your logic to move hdr2.h to the sources of hdr_maker1.  I appreciate your clarification regarding my misunderstanding of add_xxx(yyy sources) and header files.  So indeed, header files are ignored by compiler but used by the cmake logic.  I'll remove the extraneous DEPENDS and post a summary answer once I have it complete.  Many thanks.  I'd upvote you if I could upvote comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Tsvarev, here is the rewritten solution.

```
# specifying hdr1.h as one of the sources will chain hdr1.h to
# be made by its generator.
add_library(app STATIC app.c hdr1.h)

# specifying hdr2.h as one of the source will chain hdr2.h to
# be made by its generator.
add_executable(hdr_maker1 src1.c hdr2.h)

# hdr2.h can be made without dependencies
add_executable(hdr_maker2 src2.c)

# These are used a custom targets since in real project,
# the making of the makers will be conditional.  In the
# first build the makes are built.  The second time
# the .exes will be found and used to build the source. 
# ie. the .exes are not built.
add_custom_target(HDR_MAKER2 DEPENDS hdr2.h)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT hdr2.h COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:hdr_maker2> hdr2.h)

add_custom_target(HDR_MAKER1 DEPENDS hdr1.h)
add_custom_command(OUTPUT hdr1.h COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:hdr_maker1> hdr1.h)
```

Comment: If library and executalbe are the only users of corresponding headers, you may omit `add_custom_target` calls. In that case commands which produce the headers will be part of the targets `app` and `hdr_maker1` correspondingly.